# customize ion-select-popover scroll bar for web

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

is there a way to customize the scroll bar for ion-select , ion-select-popover

I tried different CSS webkit options but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, ionic components use shadow-dom. You cannot edit shadow-dom css.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a way, you have to put the following global.css

```
ion-content, ng-template {
    --offset-bottom: auto !important;
    --overflow: auto;
    background: var(--ion-toolbar-background, var(--ion-background-color, #f4f5f8)) !important;
    overflow: auto;
    
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #aaa;
    }
    
    /* Barra de desplazamiento horizontal */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-horizontal {
        height: 5px;
        width: 10px;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
        background: #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover:horizontal {
        background: #aaa;
    }
}
ion-popover{
    ion-content::part(scroll){
        overflow: initial;
        background: red;
    }
    ion-select-popover{
        background-color: white;
        overflow: auto;
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 5px;
            height: 10px;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #aaa;
        }
        
        /* Barra de desplazamiento horizontal */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-horizontal {
            height: 5px;
            width: 10px;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
            background: #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover:horizontal {
            background: #aaa;
        }
    }
}
```